# Signal/slot between 2 objects of different classes

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I have a question concerning Signal-Slots:

I have a file `userinterface.cpp` that has 2 objects of 2 classes `MoveSeries` and `Chart`:

```
MoveSeries * MOVE_SERIES  ;
MOVE_SERIES = new MoveSeries( this);
```

and

```
Chart * CHART  ;
CHART  = new Chart ( this);
```

In my `userinterface.cpp` I have `ui.Diagramm` as an object of type `Chart`.

**Now I want to have `Chart` communicate with `MoveSeries`. Can I do that with a direct Signal-Slot in `userinterface.cpp`? Something like that** :

```
 Userinterface.cpp:
   .
   .
   .
    connect(   ui.Diagram   , SIGNAL( send_BarValue( double val   )),
               MOVE_SERIES  , SLOT( on_BarValueReceived (double val) )) ;

   ...
```

Or can I only have Signal-Slots between `MoveSeries` <-> `Userinterface` and `Chart` <-> `Userinterface`?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried your solution? If so, you know the answer (yes, you can do that)

Comment: Yes I have tried, but it didn`t work, so that was my first Idea. Now that I know it could work, It seems that I have a problem with the parameters  Thanky a lot!

Comment: Yes, you can. You can even do Signals to Signal connections.
 It did not work for you? Can you show us your code?

Are you sure that MOVE_SERIES inherits from QObject and has this slot defined? (same for ui form does it have signals defined?)

Comment: Try using the search box, or even better - reading the documentation.

Comment: Also make sure all your classes with signals and slots have the `Q_OBJECT` macro, otherwise connection won't be possible. Usually connection problems (not existing slots, etc.) are logged to the console when running, you may also take a look at it.

Answer (score 3):

Your solution works, but it's written in the wrong way, you cannot pass values on the connect SIGNAL or SLOT calls, just the type.

```
 connect(ui.Diagram   , SIGNAL( send_BarValue(double)),
           MOVE_SERIES    ,SLOT( on_BarValueReceived (double) )) ;
```

But this would also be bad, this is Qt4 style connect, and it would compile and run, but if you mistyped anything there you wouldn't get an error in build tyme.

prefer to use the new Signal / Slot syntax:

```
 connect(   ui.Diagram   , &DiagramClass::end_BarValue,
           MOVE_SERIES    ,&MOVE_SERIESClass::on_BarValueReceived) ;
```

this way the connections will be compile-time checked, reducing the number of issues you may encounter.